# frames on note page, correct frame numbering

Tags: beamer, page-numbering, pgfpages

> TLDR: Using `\addtocounter{framenumber}{*value*}` decreases counter by 3x*value*.

Hello,

for an upcoming presentation I'd like to create a dual screen presentation. I want my noteslides to show the actual frame + my notes.
So I'm using frames inside my notes.
This works pretty well, but of course these note frames increase the *framenumber* counter and the second slide my listeners will see will have the frame number 3 (instead of 2).

I thought this could easily be fixed with

```
\addtobeamertemplate{note page}{\addtocounter{framenumber}{value}}.
```

In theory now every frame inside a note (unwantedly) increases *framenumber* and every note decreases the *framenumber* which leads to no change of *framenumber* inside a note after all. But that's where things get strange. Using the above code results in decreasing framenumbers.
Using different values instead of -1 shows that *framenumber* is always increases by three times the value.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

%may have to be modified to fit your system
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}

\usetheme{Frankfurt}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]

\usepackage{pgfpages}
\setbeamertemplate{note page}[plain]
\addtobeamertemplate{note page}{%
    \addtocounter{framenumber}{0}} %no effect while 0

\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \titlepage
\end{frame}
            \note{\begin{frame}{title}{}
                    \begin{itemize}
                        \item notes for introduction 
                    \end{itemize}
                  \end{frame}
                }

\begin{frame}{First Slide}{Subtitle}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item information
        \item more information
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
            \note{\begin{frame}{First Slide}{Subtitle}
                    \begin{itemize}
                        \item information + notes
                        \item more information +notes
                        \begin{itemize}
                            \item even more notes
                        \end{itemize}
                    \end{itemize}
                  \end{frame}
                }
\end{document}
```

result with value=0
[image: result with value=0]
result with value=-1
[image: result with value=-1]

Why is this happening? What do I have to change to get the wanted effect?

Workaround I already know:
Using `\addtocounter{framenumber}{-1}` in each note leads to correct numbering. Shouldn't `\addtobeamertemplate{note page}{...}` have exactly the same effect as writing it in every note?

Greetings an thanks if you read till here. :-P

Edit: Basically samcarter had the solution. I added a few lines, to modify the textsizes an enumeration items.

```
\AtBeginNote{
    \usebeamertemplate{frametitle}

    \setbeamertemplate{itemize/enumerate body begin}{\footnotesize}
    \setbeamertemplate{itemize/enumerate subbody begin}{\footnotesize}
    \setbeamertemplate{itemize/enumerate subsubbody begin}{\footnotesize}

    \setbeamercolor{itemize item}{fg=blue}
    \setbeamercolor{itemize subitem}{fg=blue}
    \setbeamercolor{itemize subsubitem}{fg=blue}

    \setbeamertemplate{itemize item}[circle]
    \setbeamertemplate{itemize subitem}[endash]
    \setbeamertemplate{itemize subsubitem}[triangle]
}
```

Comment: another workaround would be to add `[noframenumbering]` for the frames inside notes.

Comment: Don't use the notes outside of frames and don't give them additional frames, notes will create them on their own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't use notes outside a frame environment. The content belongs to the frame and this just creates additional frames.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

%may have to be modified to fit your system
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}

\usetheme{Frankfurt}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]

\usepackage{pgfpages}
\setbeamertemplate{note page}[plain]
\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen}

\AtBeginNote{\usebeamertemplate{frametitle}}

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}
        \titlepage
        \note{
            \begin{itemize}
                \item notes for introduction 
            \end{itemize}
        }
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}{First Slide}{Subtitle}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item information
            \item more information
        \end{itemize}
        \note{
            \begin{itemize}
                \item information + notes
                \item more information +notes
                \begin{itemize}
                    \item even more notes
                \end{itemize}
            \end{itemize}
    }
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This solves the numbering issue but leaves me without a title or subtitle on my notes slide. Is there a way to access the actual frametitle? Then I could add a custom headbar to the note page template.

Comment: @Nico To get the title back to the note pages I added `\AtBeginNote{\usebeamertemplate{frametitle}}`. If you want a different layout, copy the definition of the frametitle template and create a new template. Can you be a bit more precise how the header of the note pages should look like? From your second slide I assumed it should be the same as in the normal frame.

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out. I just didn't see that line. That's exactly what I want.

Comment: Since '\usebeamertitle{frametitle}' messes with the item sizes (subitems are bigger than items) I added a bit of code to modify it to my liking. I edited my question.